# Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /customers] with attributes [hasRole('ROLE_user')]

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-security, keycloak, roles

I am trying to connect a SpringBoot application with Keycloak. I have a user called 'user1' with the role 'user' in Keycloak. I have a External page (where everybody can access) and 'customers' page, when a user clicks on 'customers' he must log into Keycloak writing his username and password, if that user has the role 'user' in keycloak, he must be able to access to the customers page and see its content, if else, the page must show a message saying: "you are have not the required roles to access" and redirect him to the 'external page'

I have 2 questions:

## 1. Logging as a user with the 'user' role:

When I log with a user (user1) with 'user' role in Keycloak, it shows a blank page instead of the customers page, and this is the trace of the error:

```
2023-06-18T13:42:40.173+02:00 DEBUG 11335 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] .s.o.c.w.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [user1], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=fFVskpu9pDhEfUNb6eYxiw, sub=95240b79-d654-4291-b81a-533e55073e01, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8090/realms/SpringBootKeycloak, typ=ID, preferred_username=user1, given_name=, nonce=5Hz2cXhlixn2B2uOLKXdbGpUwqduJIjbPOIITdh92Ec, sid=33f9f427-7ecb-4afa-8bcb-2b08f25d30e5, aud=[appweb], acr=0, azp=appweb, auth_time=2023-06-18T11:33:16Z, exp=2023-06-18T11:47:40Z, session_state=33f9f427-7ecb-4afa-8bcb-2b08f25d30e5, family_name=, iat=2023-06-18T11:42:40Z, jti=827be10c-902e-4c28-b047-63fd950727a9}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=C3E666B8943BC59BEC78D8743C738C7F], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]
2023-06-18T13:42:40.173+02:00 DEBUG 11335 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to /customers
2023-06-18T13:42:40.177+02:00 DEBUG 11335 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /customers
2023-06-18T13:42:40.179+02:00 DEBUG 11335 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [user1], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=fFVskpu9pDhEfUNb6eYxiw, sub=95240b79-d654-4291-b81a-533e55073e01, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8090/realms/SpringBootKeycloak, typ=ID, preferred_username=user1, given_name=, nonce=5Hz2cXhlixn2B2uOLKXdbGpUwqduJIjbPOIITdh92Ec, sid=33f9f427-7ecb-4afa-8bcb-2b08f25d30e5, aud=[appweb], acr=0, azp=appweb, auth_time=2023-06-18T11:33:16Z, exp=2023-06-18T11:47:40Z, session_state=33f9f427-7ecb-4afa-8bcb-2b08f25d30e5, family_name=, iat=2023-06-18T11:42:40Z, jti=827be10c-902e-4c28-b047-63fd950727a9}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=C3E666B8943BC59BEC78D8743C738C7F], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2023-06-18T13:42:40.180+02:00 DEBUG 11335 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /customers] with attributes [hasRole('ROLE_user')]
```

The application, knows that the user who is signing in is 'user1' but the role is not reconized. Here is my SecurityConfig code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

    private final KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler;

    SecurityConfig(KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler) {
        this.keycloakLogoutHandler = keycloakLogoutHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/customers*")
                .hasRole("user")
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll();
        http
                .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/customers",true)
                .failureUrl("/external"))
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutUrl("/logout")
                        .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler)
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/"));

        http.oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
                .jwt(withDefaults())
        );
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .build();
    }
```

This is my WebController class

```
@Controller
public class WebController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;


    @GetMapping(path = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "external";
    }

    @GetMapping("/logout")
    public String logout(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        request.logout();
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/customers")
    public String customers(Principal principal, Model model) {
        return "customers";
    }
```

What should I change or add to my code in order to the role to be recognized and the customers page be shown?

## 2. Logging as a user with no 'user' role

As I told you before, in this case, I would like to appear a message saying "you have not the required roles to access" and then redirect him to the externals page
What should I add to my SecurityConfig class or to my project in order to obtain this??
This is my keycloakLogoutHandler class:

```
@Component
public class KeycloakLogoutHandler implements LogoutHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KeycloakLogoutHandler.class);
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public KeycloakLogoutHandler(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                       Authentication auth) {
        logoutFromKeycloak((OidcUser) auth.getPrincipal());
    }

    private void logoutFromKeycloak(OidcUser user) {
        String endSessionEndpoint = user.getIssuer() + "/protocol/openid-connect/logout";
        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromUriString(endSessionEndpoint)
                .queryParam("id_token_hint", user.getIdToken().getTokenValue());

        ResponseEntity<String> logoutResponse = restTemplate.getForEntity(
                builder.toUriString(), String.class);
        if (logoutResponse.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
            logger.info("Successfulley logged out from Keycloak");
        } else {
            logger.error("Could not propagate logout to Keycloak");
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you in advanced!!! :)

I expect:

1. For users logged as a user with 'user' role to be able to see 'customers' page
2. For users logged as a user with no 'user' role to be shown a message saying 'you dont have the required roles to access' and redirected to 'external' page